# Logging SQL Errors with Execution String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, logging, execution

I have been searching and cannot seem to find an answer for logging execution strings from inside a catch. I have a number of stored procedures that I work with and I would like to log the error information and execution string into a table when an error has occurred. For example I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dev_error
(
error_number INT,
error_procedure NVARCHAR(500),
error_message NVARCHAR(MAX),
....
procedure_call NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

I would like to be able to insert the execution string that was used to call the procedure into the procedure_call field but I am having a heck of a time finding an answer for this. I have tried using sys.parameters to pull the params and create a string, but I have trouble expanding the variable to the actual value it holds. Does anyone have any insight into a way I can accomplish this.

Comment: You may not need the procedure_call for logging. U will get procedure name by using ERROR_PROCEDURE(). Just make a string by concatenating input parameters.

Comment: I would like it to perform dynamically so that I might be able to input this in any procedure. I could do this statically inside a single call but I would like to copy this logic to a range of procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did this by writing to file but as you want to insert into table, you may do this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1]
    @Param1 AS VARCHAR(10)
    ,@Param2 AS INT
    ,@Param3 AS DATE
    ,@Param4 AS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    // Procedure Body
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @Error_Params AS VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT ' @Param1 = ' + @Param1 + ', @Param2 = ' + CAST(@Param2 AS VARCHAR(250)) + ', @Param3 = ' + CAST(@Param3 AS VARCHAR(250)) +', @Param4 = ' + CAST(@Param4 AS VARCHAR(250)))
    INSERT INTO dev_error
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), @Error_Params
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Any thoughts on creating this dynamically without knowing the input/output parameters before hand. I would like to generate them dynamically for use in multiple procedures.

Comment: Yeah this could be done. But why on earth you wanna do that? Isn't it more flexible, optimized and well- structured way to do in catch block of all SPs'? And also if you don't do it in all SPs' how u r going to find from error logging sp that which one of your other Sp causing exceptions?